# How can you create a buffer of the same size as a file?

Tags: zig

I would like to avoid making a set size buffer because of things like a file being too big, or small enough that there is empty space in the buffer. An `ArenaAllocator` sounds promising since you can allocate more space as needed. Is there a "proper" way to do this, i.e. load a .json file passed as a command line argument into a buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can you create a buffer of the same size as a file?

You can request file's size and allocate the same amount of memory:

```
var file = try std.fs.cwd().openFile("file.txt", .{ open = true }));

const file_size = (try file.stat()).size;
var buffer = try allocator.alloc(u8, file_size);
```

Then you can read the file by using `readNoEof`:

```
try file.reader().readNoEof(buffer);
```

Alternatively, you can use `File`'s `readToEndAlloc` function:

```
const size_limit = std.math.maxInt(u32); // or any other suitable limit
var result = try file.readToEndAlloc(allocator, size_limit);
```

Comment: On master 0.9.0 I had to replace `.{ open = true }` with `std.fs.O_RDONLY` but this probably works for stable

Comment: If the file is available at compile time, you could use the `@embedFIle` function: https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#embedFile

Answer (score 2):

using `GeneralPurposeAllocator`. you can learn more about allocators in https://youtu.be/vHWiDx_l4V0

```rs
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
    defer _ = gpa.deinit();
    const allocator = &gpa.allocator;
    const args = try std.process.argsAlloc(allocator);
    defer std.process.argsFree(allocator, args);
    const file = try std.fs.cwd().openFile(args[1], .{});
    const file_content = try file.readToEndAlloc(allocator, 1024 * 1024); // 1MB max read size
    defer allocator.free(file_content);
    std.debug.print("{s}", .{file_content});
}
```

Comment: This works in conjunction with the answer @sigod provided, thank you

Answer (score 2):

On 0.10.0-dev.2345+9747303d1, here's what worked for me:

```rs
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    var file = try std.fs.cwd().openFile("test.ts", .{ .mode = .read_only });
    const file_size = (try file.stat()).size;
    const allocator = std.heap.page_allocator;
    var buffer = try allocator.alloc(u8, file_size);
    try file.reader().readNoEof(buffer);

    std.debug.print("{s}\n", .{buffer});
}
```

`OpenFlags` for `.openFile` is defined here:
https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/master/lib/std/fs/file.zig#L80

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers worked for me in Zig today sine a few interfaces changed (e.g. allocator -> allocator()). Here is what worked for me (Dec 2022):

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
    defer _ = gpa.deinit();
    const allocator = &gpa.allocator();
    var file = try std.fs.cwd().openFile("./sample.txt", .{});
    const file_content = try file.readToEndAlloc(allocator.*, 10 * 1024 * 1024); // 10MB read
    defer allocator.free(file_content);
    std.debug.print("{s}", .{file_content});
}
```